# find the orthogonal matrix P?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

[image]

my attempt ; first i was taking $P = \operatorname{id}_3$..this was not satisfied and after that i was trying in taking some  upper triangular matrix ,but i could not get the matrix  who satisfied the $PAP^{-1} = B$

Im confused ..PLiz help  me ,,and tell me the solution

Comment: You can go from $A$ to $B$ by changing the columns, so you can look for $P$ as permutation matrix. From there it should not be too compicated if you understand change of basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let$$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{, }e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{, and }e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$Then

- $A.e_2=B.e_1=0$;
- $A.e_1=e_2$ and $B.e_2=e_1$;
- $A.e_3=e_1$ and $B.e_3=e_2$.

Do you see how similar they are?

So, take$$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$The matrix $P$ (which is clearly orthogonal) was chosen so that $P.e_2=e_1$, $P.e_1=e_2$, and $P.e_3=e_3$. So, $P.A.P^{-1}=B$, as you wanted.

Comment: As I understand,, i have checked all  A.e2=0=B.e1           Ae1=e2 and B.e2=e1 and Ae3 = e1 and B .e3 = e2,,,all are correct ,But  im not getting how u transform this in Matrix P,,,can u elaborate in detail  @ Jose carlos Santos

Comment: There is a pattern here. $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis such that $B.e_1=0$, $B.e_2=e_1$, and $B.e_3=e_2$. Is there a basis $\{e_1',e_2',e_3'\}$ such that $A.e_1'=0$, $A.e_2'=e_1'$, and $A.e_3'=e_2'$? Yes, there is: take $e_1'=e_2$, $e_2'=e_1$, and $e_3'=e_3$. So, take $P$ such that $P.e_1'=e_1$, $P.e_2'=e_2$, and $P.e_3'=e_3$. So, $P.A.P^{-1}.e_1=P.A.e_1'=P.0=0$, $P.A.P^{-1}.e_2=e_1$ and $P.A.P^{-1}.e_3=e_2$. Therefore, $P.A.P^{-1}=B$.

Comment: thanks a lot @ Jose Carlos ,,,

Comment: @legohlegoh If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.